# Fill NANs in a dataFrame with values with same atributes such as weekday and hour ( Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to know how I can replace the NANS of my DataFrame by the mean of the others at the same hour and day of the week.

For example, I have several NANs from 11:00pm on Wednesday to 10:00am on Thursday. It doesn`t matter the month, only the hour and weekday.
What I did was create another dataFrame call dfgrouped:

dfgrouped = df.groupby(['Weekday','Hour']).mean()

Now that I have this dataFrame, how can I used it in conjunction with df.isnull()?

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set an index on df that matches what you grouped on.  Then you can use `df.update` with `overwrite=false` which will fill the missing with the other frame.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?  df.head(10).to_dict()

Comment: Here you have  df.head(2).dict():                                           {'Activa': {0: 338.21500000000003, 1: 328.76750000000004},
 'Aparente': {0: 346.53999999999996, 1: 332.28750000000002},
 'Building': {0: 'Quimica', 1: 'Quimica'},
 'Hour': {0: 13, 1: 14},
 'Month': {0: 'Jun', 1: 'Jun'},
 'Month_num': {0: 6, 1: 6},
 'Reactiva': {0: -70.599999999999994, 1: -46.682500000000005},
 'Timestamp': {0: Timestamp('2012-06-01 13:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2012-06-01 14:00:00')},
 'Week': {0: 22, 1: 22},
 'Weekday': {0: 'Fri', 1: 'Fri'},
 'Weekday_num': {0: 4, 1: 4},
 'Year': {0: 2012, 1: 2012}}

Comment: How can I set and index on df that matches what I grouped (dfgrouped)?? Sorry  for my lack of details , but I don`t know how to show properly my problem and my df.

Comment: Maybe my answer can help. Tell me.

Comment: I've checked it now and it doesn't work. I have an error in the last sentence. TypeError: isnull() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my comprehension of your question.

```
sample = {'Activa': {0: np.nan, 1: 328.76750000000004}, 'Aparente': {0: np.nan, 1: 332.28750000000002}, 'Building': {0: 'Quimica', 1: 'Quimica'}, 'Hour': {0: 13, 1: 14}, 'Month': {0: 'Jun', 1: 'Jun'}, 'Month_num': {0: 6, 1: 6}, 'Reactiva': {0: -70.599999999999994, 1: -46.682500000000005}, 'Timestamp': {0: pd.to_datetime('2012-06-01 13:00:00'), 1: pd.to_datetime('2012-06-01 14:00:00')}, 'Week': {0: 22, 1: 22}, 'Weekday': {0: 'Fri', 1: 'Fri'}, 'Weekday_num': {0: 4, 1: 4}, 'Year': {0: 2012, 1: 2012}}
# There is a nan value in the activa column
df = DataFrame(sample)
# Performing the groupby as you do
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Week','Weekday']).mean()
# Setting the same index on the original DataFrame
df = df.set_index(['Week','Weekday'])
# Filling nan values with the mean
df = df.fillna(df_grouped)
df

# The result
                Activa  Aparente Building  Hour Month  Month_num  Reactiva  \
Week Weekday                                                                 
22   Fri      328.7675  332.2875  Quimica    13   Jun          6  -70.6000   
     Fri      328.7675  332.2875  Quimica    14   Jun          6  -46.6825   

                       Timestamp  Weekday_num  
Week Weekday                                   
22   Fri     2012-06-01 13:00:00            4  
     Fri     2012-06-01 14:00:00            4
```